# Como disparar evento keydown javascript puro

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Como faço para disparar eventos via código ex: `keydown`, `keypress` e depois correr uma função quando a tecla `Enter` for pressionada, com javascript puro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
el.addEventListener('keydown', function(){
   //código a correr aqui...
});
```

Se tiveres um elemento numa variável podes juntar o [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) que vai escutar o evento que passares no primeiro argumento, e vai correr a função que passares no segundo argumento.

Para saberes se a tecla pressionada foi o `Enter` precisas de verificar se o `event.keyCode == 13`.

Exemplo:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var mostrador = document.querySelector('#mostrador');
var enviado = document.querySelector('#enviado');
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return enviar(this.value);
  }
  mostrador.innerHTML = this.value.split('').reverse().join('');
});

function enviar(texto) {
  enviado.innerHTML = 'Enviado: ' + texto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <label>
    <p>Escreve algo aqui e carrega "Enter":</p>
  </label>
  <input>
</section>
<section>
  <p id="mostrador"></p>
  <p id="enviado"></p>
</section>
```

Comment: mas para eu forço execução um keydown já definido. ex: tenho um chat ele usa keydown para enviar msg. então quero adicionar valor via  o `val()`   e assim enviar via keydown (enter).

Comment: @EduardoAvilaMalheiros queres que quando o `Enter` for pressionado ele execute uma função, é isso?

Comment: @Sergio, acho que ele quer inserir um texto dinamicamente, via javascript, e depois disparar o evento keydown, como o `trigger` do JQuery.

Comment: @Sergio na verdade eu tenho que forçar a fução enter via codigo. disparar evento  como Samir falo.

Comment: @EduardoAvilaMalheiros juntei isso na resposta

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo funcionando:

```
// Add um listener
document.addEventListener("nome-do-evento", function(e) {
  console.log(e.detail); // Exibe "Exemplo do evento" no console
});

// Criando o evento
var event = new CustomEvent("nome-do-evento", { "detail": "Exemplo do evento" });

// Chama o evento
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Copiei essa resposta do seguinte post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20548330/407213

Edit:

Executando um evento de keydown de um elemento HTML especifico:

```
// Seleciona o elemento
var element = document.querySelector('input');

// Adiciona (mais um) listener para exibir no console a key 'pressionada'
element.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){ console.log(e.key) });

// Cria um objeto do evento especifico
var e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { key : "Q"});

// Chama o evento
element.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: esse dispatchEvent(event) so executa evento que eu adicionei acima.  mas caso eu tenho 2 outros evento keydown padrão no input. como faço para executá-los ?

Comment: Editei a resposta acima para explicar como executar o evento de keydown dos elementos HTML.